# Object doesn't support this property or method IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am getting an error in IE8: `Object doesn't support this property or method` yet everything works in the other browsers no problem. When IE is refreshed the error goes away and the slideshow displays properly.

Here is the code.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

The line causing the error is `$('.flexslider').flexslider({`

I've tried various solutions to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Seems like the `flexslider` plugin isn't getting loaded properly.

Comment: Is jQuery definitely being loaded before the flexslider js? Also are you running any other JS libraries on your page? If so there may be a conflict with the $ operator.

Comment: Did you load the `flexslider` js?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer and it wasn't in the line of code I posted. I was using

```
<script defer src="scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

to load the script and I changed it to

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "slide",
          start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
         }
    });
});
```

This makes use of jQuery.ready(), which is more reliable than $(window).load() cross-browser.

In fact, you can replace $(window).load() altogether (if you don't need to wait for images or etc).

```
$(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading')
    }
});
```

Also, make sure the script that includes the flexslider is included in the "head" section of your page.  If you include it in the body or load it by creating a DOM  node, neither load nor ready will guarantee that it has been executed.

Comment: But why did you still leave that `$(window).load()` there? :)

Comment: Maybe the `window.load` is required to make sure all images are loaded before the code is initialized.  Either way, it does not hurt anything to have it there.

Comment: Good point...your comment came as I was editing the answer :)

Comment: Actually, Sparky is right - ready does not mean window.load.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587939/what-exactly-does-document-ready-guarantee).  If you need to wait for resources (images, etc), then you have to also include window.load.

Comment: Have tried all of the suggestions. Even moved code around and still displays an error only in IE8. Works fine in all other browsers. In IE8 if you navigate off the page then go back everything works fine with no errors. Strange, I am assuming something isn't loading in the proper order but can't figure it out.